# Power BI Categories and Subcategories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 columns in Power BI - Main categories of Costs, and Subcategories of Costs and Values. I would like the preview to be in the same row, as shown in the second table.
This is the table I have.

| Category | Subcategory | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acqusition Costs | Brokerage Commissions | 9000 |
| Acqusition Costs | Other Commissions | 3000 |
| Maintenance Costs | Hardware Maintenance | 5000 |
| Maintenance Costs | Software Maintenance | 5000 |

And this is the table I need to show in Power BI

| Costs | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Acqusition Costs | 12000 |
| *Brokerage Commissions | *9000 |
| *Other Commissions | *3000 |
| Maintenance Costs | 10000 |
| *Hardware Maintenance | *5000 |
| *Software Maintenance | *5000 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make a table? Or is this a visualization for a PowerBI a report?

You wouldn't make an actual table object in your PowerBI Model this way. Your first table can be abstracted upon by either DAX or the available PowerBI visuals to get the result you want.

For example, using your initial dataset in the model:

[image]

This can be abstracted with PowerBI's Matrix visual to get your desired output:

[image]

Notice how you can stack categorical columns within the 'Rows' visualization section. This provides the effect of a hierarchy between your categories.

Hope this helps.